# Is it possible to route packets using iptables only without enabling ipforwarding?

Tags: linux, iptables, kernel

I'm wondering if it is possible to do routing using iptables only, without using ip_forwarding flag in kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. IPTables is for firewalling and other packet mangling, which is a separate function from forwarding.

Furthermore, routing is different than forwarding.

Comment: But How about this article? https://scalingo.com/blog/iptables

Comment: What about that article makes you think you don't need forwarding enabled?

Comment: unless the mentioned article is incorrect at all.